# Couchbase backup and restote through copy data files

Tags: backup, restore, couchbase, couchdb

I was exploring couchbase backup and restoring procedures then we found standard procedures. But, if I can take data directory backup in the form of `.tar` and `untar` data directory whenever restore required, will it work?

```
tar -cvf /opt/couchbase/var/lib/data  -----backup

tar -xvf xxx.tar  ----restore
```